# Configure SMTP server windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

I am configuring a local network and for some reason I can't get server to send an email. I already install the SMTP server and configured using this tutorial http://www.itsolutionskb.com/2008/11/installing-and-configuring-windows-server-2008-smtp-server/ but when I try to send an email using code, the email gets pickedup from mailroot/pickup and dropped in mailroot/queue and stays in queue forever, it never goes anywhere, I even tried dropping a basic mail.txt file with this in it:

```
to:tbill@externaldomainname.com
from:testuser@internaldomain.com
subject:This is a test.
this is a test.
```

still the same thing happens. Is the smtp server not configured right, is their something else I am missing, because this is my first time setting up an smtp server

Comment: Do you have business account with your ISP, to send mail to a external domain you require business account. However you can send mail locally.

Comment: oh so I need a static IP address to make it happen first?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you're also running your own DNS server it makes sense to also do the MX records for all mail (as you're running SMTP, i assume also POP3/IMAP?) but if you're not then an external mail server (for the MX records) to handle the mail to your server is the better solution

Comment: You ISP might be blocking port 25 (SMTP), call them up and verify if the port is open

Answer (score 0):

One vital thing this misses out is configuring the domains.  You need to add the Domains that the server is allowed to relay for (in this example `internaldomain.com`)

Also, you can try send email from telnet (as per last screenshot), as follows (change server to your server name or IP):

```
telnet server 25
helo
mail from: testuser@internaldomain.com
rcpt to: tbill@externaldomainname.com
data
subject: This is a test.
this is a test.
.
quit
```

Comment: what do you mean by relay to?

Comment: Not relay to, relay for. With SMTP server you have to specify the local Domains (see Step 6 in the background, under Domains add whichever local Domains they are. For example, my Exchange 2010 has 89 domains registered to it, if I try send an email from googlemail.com for example, it will tell me I can't because it's not in the list of allowed domains.

Comment: you're not understanding my question, I am not trying to send an email from google. I have a server domain name is: internaldomain and I want to send an email from the server to a google account or yahoo account

Comment: Yes, so under the Domains under SMTP Server, you need to put your domain name there else the server won't relay for your domain (you need to specify the domain(s) that emails are going to be sent FROM)